# Problem in installation of snapd on Oracle Linux Server 7.6 (based on RHEL 7.6) using yum

Tags: installation, yum, rhel7, snapcraft, oraclelinux

First step is - `sudo yum install snapd` 
This seems to work fine download the dependencies and all and setup is completed 
Installed Version : snapd.x86_64 0:2.45-1.el7 
Second step is - `sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket` 
Gives output as > Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/snapd.socket to /usr/lib/systemd/system/snapd.socket. 
Now checking status - `sudo systemctl status snapd` gives:

```
   ● snapd.service - Snap Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2020-12-07 11:17:28 IST; 16min ago
 Main PID: 5726 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

systemd[1]: snapd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for snapd.service
systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
systemd[1]: Unit snapd.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of snapd.service.
systemd[1]: snapd.service failed.
systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for snapd.service
systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
systemd[1]: snapd.service failed.
```

Possible Solutions tried- 1) Re-installation after purge, 2) enabled socket and service after reboot again.

`journalctl -u snapd.service` output:

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2020-12-09 11:21:36 IST, end at Thu 2020-12-17 12:40:16 IST. --
Dec 17 12:36:45 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Dec 17 12:36:45 whf00jfw snapd[4639]: AppArmor status: apparmor not enabled
Dec 17 12:36:45 whf00jfw snapd[4639]: daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.45-1.el7 (series 16; classic; devmode) ol/7.6 (amd64) linux/4.14.35-1902.304.6.el7uek.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw snapd[4639]: daemon.go:436: adjusting startup timeout by 30s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw snapd[4639]: cannot run daemon: state startup errors: [cannot obtain snap-seccomp version information: fork/exec /usr/lib/snapd/snap
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Unit snapd.service entered failed state.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of snapd.service.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service failed.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw snapd[4673]: AppArmor status: apparmor not enabled
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw snapd[4673]: daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.45-1.el7 (series 16; classic; devmode) ol/7.6 (amd64) linux/4.14.35-1902.304.6.el7uek.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw snapd[4673]: daemon.go:436: adjusting startup timeout by 30s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw snapd[4673]: cannot run daemon: state startup errors: [cannot obtain snap-seccomp version information: fork/exec /usr/lib/snapd/snap
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Unit snapd.service entered failed state.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of snapd.service.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service failed.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw snapd[4699]: AppArmor status: apparmor not enabled
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw snapd[4699]: daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.45-1.el7 (series 16; classic; devmode) ol/7.6 (amd64) linux/4.14.35-1902.304.6.el7uek.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw snapd[4699]: daemon.go:436: adjusting startup timeout by 30s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw snapd[4699]: cannot run daemon: state startup errors: [cannot obtain snap-seccomp version information: fork/exec /usr/lib/snapd/snap
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Unit snapd.service entered failed state.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of snapd.service.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service failed.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw snapd[4745]: AppArmor status: apparmor not enabled
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw snapd[4745]: daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.45-1.el7 (series 16; classic; devmode) ol/7.6 (amd64) linux/4.14.35-1902.304.6.el7uek.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw snapd[4745]: daemon.go:436: adjusting startup timeout by 30s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw snapd[4745]: cannot run daemon: state startup errors: [cannot obtain snap-seccomp version information: fork/exec /usr/lib/snapd/snap
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Unit snapd.service entered failed state.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of snapd.service.
Dec 17 12:36:46 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service failed.
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw snapd[4775]: AppArmor status: apparmor not enabled
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw snapd[4775]: daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.45-1.el7 (series 16; classic; devmode) ol/7.6 (amd64) linux/4.14.35-1902.304.6.el7uek.
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw snapd[4775]: daemon.go:436: adjusting startup timeout by 30s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw snapd[4775]: cannot run daemon: state startup errors: [cannot obtain snap-seccomp version information: fork/exec /usr/lib/snapd/snap
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Unit snapd.service entered failed state.
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of snapd.service.
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service failed.
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for snapd.service
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Unit snapd.service entered failed state.
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of snapd.service.
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service failed.
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for snapd.service
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:36:47 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service failed.
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw snapd[5826]: AppArmor status: apparmor not enabled
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw snapd[5826]: daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.45-1.el7 (series 16; classic; devmode) ol/7.6 (amd64) linux/4.14.35-1902.304.6.el7uek.
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw snapd[5826]: daemon.go:436: adjusting startup timeout by 30s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw snapd[5826]: cannot run daemon: state startup errors: [cannot obtain snap-seccomp version information: fork/exec /usr/lib/snapd/snap
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Unit snapd.service entered failed state.
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of snapd.service.
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service failed.
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw snapd[5855]: AppArmor status: apparmor not enabled
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw snapd[5855]: daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.45-1.el7 (series 16; classic; devmode) ol/7.6 (amd64) linux/4.14.35-1902.304.6.el7uek.
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw snapd[5855]: daemon.go:436: adjusting startup timeout by 30s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw snapd[5855]: cannot run daemon: state startup errors: [cannot obtain snap-seccomp version information: fork/exec /usr/lib/snapd/snap
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Unit snapd.service entered failed state.
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of snapd.service.
Dec 17 12:40:15 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service failed.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw snapd[5952]: AppArmor status: apparmor not enabled
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw snapd[5952]: daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.45-1.el7 (series 16; classic; devmode) ol/7.6 (amd64) linux/4.14.35-1902.304.6.el7uek.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw snapd[5952]: daemon.go:436: adjusting startup timeout by 30s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw snapd[5952]: cannot run daemon: state startup errors: [cannot obtain snap-seccomp version information: fork/exec /usr/lib/snapd/snap
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Unit snapd.service entered failed state.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of snapd.service.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service failed.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw snapd[6154]: AppArmor status: apparmor not enabled
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw snapd[6154]: daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.45-1.el7 (series 16; classic; devmode) ol/7.6 (amd64) linux/4.14.35-1902.304.6.el7uek.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw snapd[6154]: daemon.go:436: adjusting startup timeout by 30s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw snapd[6154]: cannot run daemon: state startup errors: [cannot obtain snap-seccomp version information: fork/exec /usr/lib/snapd/snap
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Unit snapd.service entered failed state.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of snapd.service.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service failed.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw snapd[6260]: AppArmor status: apparmor not enabled
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw snapd[6260]: daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.45-1.el7 (series 16; classic; devmode) ol/7.6 (amd64) linux/4.14.35-1902.304.6.el7uek.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw snapd[6260]: daemon.go:436: adjusting startup timeout by 30s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw snapd[6260]: cannot run daemon: state startup errors: [cannot obtain snap-seccomp version information: fork/exec /usr/lib/snapd/snap
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Unit snapd.service entered failed state.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of snapd.service.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service failed.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for snapd.service
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Unit snapd.service entered failed state.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of snapd.service.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service failed.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for snapd.service
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Dec 17 12:40:16 whf00jfw systemd[1]: snapd.service failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an issue with strict confinement not being supported on operating systems that don't use AppArmor (OL, CentOS, RHEL). There are steps needed to make that work. Did you create the symbolic link?

```
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
```

This worked for me:

```
sudo yum install snapd
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
sudo systemctl restart snapd
<restart session>
sudo snap install firefox
sudo snap install --classic nano
```

Comment: Yeah already tried all the trivial ways :(

Comment: What does `journalctl -u snapd.service` report?

Comment: Added journalctl output as well.

Comment: I updated my previous answer. Apparently strict confinement is not possible on Linux OS without AppArmor. A symbolic link is needed to support installing in less-than-strict confinement.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but still getting exactly same error. I have tried installing this way earlier as well tried again nothing changes. I have seen multiple posts on snapcraft site related to this problem and exhausted all the possible fixes given there, final outcome was that my OS might be broken so I have re-installed OS too, still no progress.

Comment: Which kernel are you running and, are virtualization or containers involved? In my case, even though snapd's status shows **inactive (dead), (code=exited, status=42)**, I can still install snaps. `sudo snap install firefox...firefox 84.0-3 from Mozilla✓ installed.` `snap    2.45-1.el7, kernel: 5.4.17-2036.100.6.1.el7uek.x86_64` on OL79

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to put a note on this, as it's one of the top results for this error message. I encountered the exact same error, but was able to find more details by trying to run snapd manually, revealing the issue to be (in my case) related to snapd-seccomp, which was out of date.

Running "yum update libseccomp" resolved the problem and allowed installation of snaps successfully.